# How to put if statement in Informix triggers in before

Tags: sql, informix

I need to make a trigger that won't allow update of "grade" where grade is 1. So, I need to make it with `before` the triggering statement. Procedure `returnMistake()` is not of a concern - it just raises `exception`.

I have the following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER changeGrade
    UPDATE OF grade ON subject
    BEFORE (
        IF (grade = 1) EXECUTE PROCEDURE returnMistake() END IF; 
    )
```

I know that I don't specify anywhere value of the `grade`, but just name of the column, but I can't put `REFERENCING OLD` because I'm using `BEFORE` and not `FOR EACH ROW`.

How can I make this? This stops at `IF` statement describing syntax error. For the matter of example, I'll put here code that is passing in Informix:

```
CREATE TRIGGER changeGrade
        UPDATE OF grade ON subject
        BEFORE (
            EXECUTE PROCEDURE returnMistake() 
        )
```

How to do it with `BEFORE`? I would know how to make it with `FOR EACH ROW` - I would just let it to be changed, and then if it was 1, change it back to the previous and calling the `returnMistake()`, although I think I'm supposed to use `BEFORE`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Informix (at current version , v12.10) don't support embedded SPL statements into a trigger "body", which make little annoying include some logical at triggers since you are obligated to create a SPL to do the job...
For more simplistic logical or filter you can use the `WHEN` option.

That said, your solution don't appear much logical for me... or you are misinterpreted the concept of `before, for each row and after` actions from a trigger.

What I means is: If you use the `before` action, the trigger will be called only once before of the UPDATE statement (no matter if this update will  affect one, non or lot of rows).
If the *before trigger* was executed only once and (most important) **before** the statement start running, how they will able to know the content of the "grade" field for all rows which could be affected?

So, if you want to create a exception if the row with "grade" content equal 1 , you are without options and need use the *`for each row` + when + stored procedure + raise exception ...*

If your database is logged (have transaction control) and this table is `standard` (not a `RAW` table) the raised exception will abort and rollback all rows affected by this update statement. This way you will reach your objective.

```
CREATE TRIGGER changeGrade
UPDATE OF grade ON subject
REFERECING OLD AS O
WHEN ( o.grade =1 )   
FOR EACH ROW ( EXECUTE PROCEDURE returnMistake() )
```